# How to place to divs with drop down lists in them next to each other?

Tags: html, css

```
<div style="width: 100%; overflow: hidden;">
<div style="margin-left: 100px; width: 600px; float: left;">
<div class="description"> 
<h2 style="color:blue">Select the appropriate version</h2>
</div>
<select>
 <option value="" disabled selected>Select version</option>
 <option value="" disabled selected>Select feature</option>
 <option value="A"> A     </option>
 <option value="B"> B </option>
 <option value="C"> C</option>
</select>

<div style=" margin-left: 350px; width: 600px; float: left;">
<div class="description">
<h2 style="color:blue">Select the appropriate category</h2>
</div>
<select>
 <option value="" disabled selected>Select feature</option>
 <option value="" disabled selected>Select category</option>
 <option value="A"> A     </option>
 <option value="B"> B </option>
 <option value="C"> C</option>
</select>

<div style="margin-left: 620px;  width: 600px; float: left;">
<div class="description">
<br>
<h2 style="color:blue">Select the feature</h2>
</div>
<select>
 <option value="" disabled selected>Select feature</option>
 <option value="" disabled selected>Select category</option>
 <option value="A"> A     </option>
 <option value="B"> B </option>
 <option value="C"> C</option>
</select>
</div>
</div>
```

I want the three divs with the drop down lists to be next to each other horizontally. I have tried using float, inline and inline block. How can it be done in HTML.

Comment: Your HTML structure is invalid, and also move the inline-style to external CSS to make it easy for debug.

Answer (score 2):

Use `inline-block` and put properly your all `divs`.

Here is an example:

```css
.selection {
  display: inline-block;
}
h1{
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 14px;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div class="selection">
    <h1>Select Option</h1>
    <select>
      <option>1</option>
      <option>2</option>
      <option>3</option>
    </select>
  </div>  
  <div class="selection">
    <h1>Select Option</h1>
    <select>
      <option>1</option>
      <option>2</option>
      <option>3</option>
    </select>
  </div>  
  <div class="selection">
    <h1>Select Option</h1>
    <select>
      <option>1</option>
      <option>2</option>
      <option>3</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<div style="float:left">
dropdown1
</div>
<div style="float:left">
dropdown2
</div>
<div style="float:left">
dropdown3
</div>
```

This will definitely work.

Problem in your code is over width. Better is you give width into % instead of px.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, your code is really badly formatted.

Your are using 7 `Div` but you are missing 2 `Div` closing tags. Close the `Div` tags properly.

You are also fixing the width of all 3 divisions, so if the screen size is smaller than the combined width of the 3 div, your div's will no longer be displayed horizontally. Give width relative like `width:30%`.

Also remove margin from the elements. Use `Padding` instead to give space between div's.

```
<html>
<body>
<div style="width: 100%; overflow: hidden;">
<div style=" width: 33%;float: left;">
<div class="description"> 
<h2 style="color:blue">Select the appropriate version</h2>
</div>
<select>
 <option value="" disabled selected>Select version</option>
 <option value="" disabled selected>Select feature</option>
 <option value="A"> A     </option>
 <option value="B"> B </option>
 <option value="C"> C</option>
</select>
</div>
<div style="float: left;width: 33%;">
<div class="description">
<h2 style="color:blue">Select the appropriate category</h2>
</div>
<select>
 <option value="" disabled selected>Select feature</option>
 <option value="" disabled selected>Select category</option>
 <option value="A"> A     </option>
 <option value="B"> B </option>
 <option value="C"> C</option>
</select>
</div>

<div style=" float: left;width: 33%;">
<div class="description">
<br>
<h2 style="color:blue">Select the feature</h2>
</div>
<select>
 <option value="" disabled selected>Select feature</option>
 <option value="" disabled selected>Select category</option>
 <option value="A"> A     </option>
 <option value="B"> B </option>
 <option value="C"> C</option>
</select>
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Problem is with your code you have 3 unclosed div tags and a lot of left margin plus try to use width and margin both in %

```
[Check pen]    (http://codepen.io/anon/pen/gPzJpr)
```

Answer (score 0):

for your `html`

```
<div class="container">
  <div id="firstDiv">
    <h1>Select the appropriate version</h1>
    <select class="" name="">
      <option value="" disabled selected>Select version</option>
      <option value="" disabled selected>Select feature</option>
      <option value="A"> A     </option>
      <option value="B"> B </option>
      <option value="C"> C</option>
    </select>
  </div>

  <div id="secondDiv">
    <h1>Select the appropriate version</h1>
    <select class="" name="">
      <option value="" disabled selected>Select version</option>
      <option value="" disabled selected>Select feature</option>
      <option value="A"> A     </option>
      <option value="B"> B </option>
      <option value="C"> C</option>
    </select>
  </div>

  <div id="thirdDiv">
    <h1>Select the appropriate version</h1>
    <select class="" name="">
      <option value="" disabled selected>Select version</option>
      <option value="" disabled selected>Select feature</option>
      <option value="A"> A     </option>
      <option value="B"> B </option>
      <option value="C"> C</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</div>
```

for your `css`:

```
div{
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    margin: 5px;
    padding: 15px;
  }
  #firstDiv{
    background-color: #ccc;
  }
  #secondDiv{
    background-color: #eee;
  }
  #thirdDiv{
    background-color: #aaa;
  }
```

Just like what @Maihan Nijat said, use external CSS to make it easier for you to debug.

Answer (score 0):

I made a few changes to your code. The absolute easiest way to solve this problem is to ensure that the width of each element could fit next to each other on the screen. Not only does this require that the text is not too large, but also that the `width` you explicitly define does not overflow.

The simple solution to your problem is to place `display: inline-block;` on the elements which you would like side by side.

```css
.left {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

  <div class="left">
    <div class="description">
      <h2 style="color:blue">Select the appropriate version</h2>
    </div>
    <select>
      <option value="" disabled selected>Select version</option>
      <option value="" disabled selected>Select feature</option>
      <option value="A">A</option>
      <option value="B">B</option>
      <option value="C">C</option>
    </select>
  </div>

  <div class="left">
    <div class="description">
      <h2 style="color:blue">Select the appropriate category</h2>
    </div>
    <select>
      <option value="" disabled selected>Select feature</option>
      <option value="" disabled selected>Select category</option>
      <option value="A">A</option>
      <option value="B">B</option>
      <option value="C">C</option>
    </select>
  </div>

  <div class="left">
    <div class="description">
      <br>
      <h2 style="color:blue">Select the feature</h2>
    </div>
    <select>
      <option value="" disabled selected>Select feature</option>
      <option value="" disabled selected>Select category</option>
      <option value="A">A</option>
      <option value="B">B</option>
      <option value="C">C</option>
    </select>
  </div>



</body>

</html>
```